# Send data from ajax in codeigniter 3 is showing 403 forbidden when csrf protection is true

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I am using csrf protection in codeigniter 3 and I want to send login details using ajax.

When I try to send data with AJAX to the controller, it is returning 403 forbidden error in the console.

Please tell me what i can do?

here is our jquery code

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#logIn').click(function() {

        var mob = $.trim($('#mob').val()); // get mobile no from view

        var psw = $.trim($('#pas').val()); // get password form view

        var lgurl = $('#logFrm').val(); // get complete url to send data

        var csrfNm = $('#csrfDl').attr('name');  // get form view (csrf_token_name)
        var csrfVl = $('#csrfDl').val();  // get from view (csrf_cookie_name)

        $.ajax({
                    url: lgurl,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                             csrfNm  : csrfVl,
                                mob  : mob,
                                psw  : psw
                          },

                    success: function (data) {

                       if (data) 
                       {
                          alert('Success');
                          console.log(data);
                          alert(data);
                       }
                    },

                    error: function (data) 
                    {
                       alert('Error');
                       console.log(data);
                        alert(data);
                    }
              });

    });

});
```

controller code

```
public function login_success()
{
    $mno = $this->input->post('mob',TRUE);
    $pas = $this->input->post('psw',TRUE);
    // $data['csrfNm'] = $this->input->post('csrfNm');

    print_r($mno);
}
```

Comment: Show us your code deep. through these two lines how can we figure out the error ?

Comment: No, don't paste the code as an answer. Edit your question.